# Generating function for parity in hooks

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, polynomials, partitions, generating-functions

Let $\lambda\vdash n$ denote an [integer partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n$ and $\frak{H}_{\lambda}$ be the multiset of [hook lengths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula) of $\lambda$. Further, let $o(\lambda)=\#$ of odd entries and $e(\lambda)=\#$ of even entries in $\frak{H}_{\lambda}$.

**Example.** If $\lambda=(4,3,1,1)$ then $\frak{H}_{\lambda}=(7,4,3,1,5,2,1,2,1)$. Also, $o(\lambda)=6$ and $e(\lambda)=3$.

> **QUESTION.** Is there a generating function for the following "parity distribution" function?
> $$F_n(q,t):=\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}q^{o(\lambda)}t^{e(\lambda)}.$$

**Examples.** Here is a short list of such polynomials:
\begin{align*}
F_1(q,t)&=q, \qquad \qquad F_2(q,t)=2qt, \qquad F_3(q,t)=q^3+2q^2t, \\
F_4(q,t)&=5q^2t^2, \qquad F_5(q,t)=2q^4t+5q^3t^2.
\end{align*}

**Remark.** Observe that $\sum_{n\geq0}F_n(q,q)\,x^n=\prod_{i\geq1}\frac1{1-q^ix^i}$.

**Remark.** The coefficient of $q^nt^n$ in $F_{2n}(q,t)$ is the convolution of $\sum_{k=0}^np(k)p(n-k)$ where $p(n)$ are the [partitions numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the generating function is
$$\sum_{n\geq 0} F_{n}(q,t)x^n=\prod_{k\geq 1}\frac{(1-q^{2k}x^{2k})^2}{1-q^kx^k}\cdot \prod _{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{(1-q^kt^kx^{2k})^2}.$$
This follows from the usual bijection between partitions and 2-cores (corresponding to the first product on the right) and 2-quotients (corresponding to the second product) upon realizing that the boxes in a partition with even hook length are in bijection with the boxes of its 2-quotient.

Incidentally these polynomials are also homogenized versions of the Poincare polynomials of G-Hilbert schemes for $G=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. For example, see Theorem 2 of "On generating series of classes of equivariant Hilbert schemes of fat points", by S.M. Gusein-Zade, I. Luengo, A. Melle Hernandez, [arXiv:0905.1779](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.1779).

Comment: Do you think this generalizes? That is, what if you look for hooks modulo $3$; a 3-parameter distribution.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan There is a straightforward generalization mod $n$, where the statistic is "number of hooks divisible by $n$".

Comment: Nice! It might be informative if you can add it to your answer.